# Intent Not Firing

Tags: android, android-intent, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I have an app that builds a temporary HTML file, then sends said file via bluetooth (using share intents) and the following code:

```
exports.sendViaBluetooth = function(file, title) {

    var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
        action: Ti.Android.ACTION_SEND
    });

    // File contains a tifileobject.nativePath
    intent.putExtraUri(Ti.Android.EXTRA_STREAM, file);

    var share = Ti.Android.createIntentChooser(intent, title);

    Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivityForResult(share, function(e) {
        // This never fires
        Ti.API.info("Finished intent:");
        Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(e, 0, 2));
    });

};
```

Sometimes this successfully pops up the share box, sometimes not. The startActivityForResult callback is never fired. The file exists at the path provided and is > 0 bytes so that's being created successfully.

Would it be possible to use Hyperloop to use native intent functionality instead of the Ti proxies?

Any help/ideas/guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this in a fashion.

The activity never starts because Ti.Android.currentActivity doesn't accurately seem to hold the current activity. If you pass in the current view, ie and then call startActivity on that, everything works as expected.

This:

```
$.report.activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Will fire the intent every single time without fail. Hopefully this helps someone who encounters the same situation.